# How do you verify/check kivy version?

Tags: kivy

This doesn't work:

```
$ kivy --version
Python 2.7.6
```

I've got `Kivy.app` installed, and it doesn't provide any version info either.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The version is printed in kivy's default logger output, or you can get it in python with:

```
python -c "import kivy; print(kivy.__version__)"
```

Comment: `kivy` is not a python module on my system, so I can't import it, and I don't know what kivy's *default logger output* is. Ah! I see. When I run: `$ kivy my_kivy_prog.py`, kivy prints a bunch of startup info to the screen, and that shows the kivy version. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the logger output that shows the kivy version:

```
$ kivy my_kivy_prog.py 

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/.kivy/logs/kivy_15-12-20_0.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <2.1 INTEL-10.4.47>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 6100>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.20>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

You can see both the kivy version and the python version in there.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is late, but you can do `$ kivy` and `import kivy`. Then you can see the version `[INFO ][Kivy]v1.9.1-dev0` in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this instead, in the terminal:

```sh
pip list | grep -i "kivy"
```

Answer (score 1):

On terminal type

> > python3
> > Then,
> > import kivy #you will see kivy version

> import kivymd # you see kivymd version